# Can a memoize function use a ES6 Map vs a hashtable?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, ecmascript-6, hashtable, memoization

**Preface:** Trying to learn [ES6 Maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) through converting a simple memoize that leverages a hash table instead.

### **Question:**

**Can the starting Object be replaced with a `new Map()`, if so, how? And are there any advantages? if not, why?**

---

**Description:**

Here's a memoize that takes function (`add`) and a starting object(`{}`). On call of the *memoized add* (`mAdd`) the parameters are [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).  Finally, the hash index is tested/sets and value is returned.

### **[LINK TO CODE](https://repl.it/E9DG/0)**

```js
const memo = (fn, hash) => (...a) => {
  return hash[a] === void 0 ?  hash[a] = fn(...a) : `${hash[a]} memo`;
};

const add = (x, y) =>  x + y;

const mAdd = memo(add, {});


console.log(mAdd(2,2));
console.log(mAdd(2,2));
```

**Not working with maps:**

```js
const memo = (fn, map) => (...a) => {
  return map.get(a) === void 0 ?  map.set(a, fn(...a)) : `${map.get(a)} memo`;
};

const add = (x, y) =>  x + y;

const mAdd = memo(add, new Map());


console.log(mAdd(2,2));
console.log(mAdd(2,2));
```

Comment: `if so, how?` - replace `{}` with `new Map()`

Comment: @JaromandaX it's not that easy? https://repl.it/E9DG/1 I've tried

Comment: So did I - and it worked for me, oddly enough

Comment: You may want to see also WeakMaps for this purpose

Comment: Could you create an answer ? I'm still not to sure if the question marked correct, is indeed the best answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that the parameters do not represent the same object. Their contents do, which is why stringifying would work.

Using an object as a hash, also performs a kind of stringify: a property `2,2` is created. (As a side note: this is not full proof, because the contents are flattened. Parameters `[1,[2,3]]` and `[1,2,3]` would both create the property `[1,2,3]` )

However since the `Map` is actually smarter in a way, the object itself is used as a key and for each call a new object is created for the parameters.

Calling with the same parameters would work, but of course that would make the function less useful:

```
var pars = [2,2];
console.log(mAdd(pars));
console.log(mAdd(pars));
```

(the method signature would have to be changed to `const memo = (fn, map) => (a) => {` for the above to work. Also note that `Map.set` returns the map object itself and not the value that is being set).

The easiest implementation is to stringify the key. Safest is `JSON.stringify` to handle all situations, but if you're relatively sure of the contents, you could do something like `join` instead:

```
const memo = (fn, map) => (...a) => {
    const key = a.join(',');
  if(map.has(key))
        return `${map.get(key)} memo`;
    let res = fn(...a);
  map.set(key, res );
  return res;
};
```

Creating the key can be done several ways. stringify is possible, perhaps even  `const key = uneval(a);` Some sort of hash integer could be created based on length and contents, but its reliability depends on the possible contents. e.g. if it is known that values never exceed 100 and the number of parameters is not overly long, a helper as `const createKey = ([a1,...a]) => a.length ? a1 + 100 * createKey(a) : a1;` can be called with `const key =createKey(a);`

Of course for the example directly adding would be always faster than the key creation and key lookup, but for general purposes the method for creating the key is the defining factor.

I realize I'm probably not saying anything new in all of this, but the bottom line is that the passed parameters do not represent the same object. That said, I'd like to suggest another option: create a branched map. The base map containing child-maps (with the first parameter as key) to either the results (with the second parameter as key) or subsequent maps to second elements.

**edit** An example of said branching (a single map can be used for different functions to reduce the memory footprint):

```js
const memoMap = new Map(); //use a general map for branches for all memoized functions, because result is stored in the child function as the key

const memo = (fn) => (...a) => {
  let key, r = a, map = memoMap;
  while(r.length){
      [key,...r] = r;      
      if(map.has(key))
       map = map.get(key);
      else
       map.set(key, map = new Map());
  }
  let res = map.get(fn); //get result for this specific function
  if(res===undefined)
   map.set(fn, res = fn(...a));
  else return `${res} memo`; //<-- line for testing purposes
  return res;
};


const add = (x, y) =>  x + y,
  subtr = (x,y) => x - y,
  mAdd = memo(add);

console.log(mAdd(2,2));
console.log(mAdd(2,2));
console.log(memo(subtr)(2,2));
console.log(memo(subtr)(2,2));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is Map uses reference of an object to identify as a key (if the provided key is an object and not a primitive type). In this case *a* variable is an array and even if it has the same values on each call but the reference of that variable is not the same thus Map understands it as a new key. Have a look at bottom code.

```js
const test = new Map();
const a = ['bla'];
test.set(a, 'b');
console.log(test.get(a));
const f = ['bla'];
console.log(test.get(f));
```

One workaround to this issue is to stringify the *a* variable.

```js
const memo = (fn, hash) => (...a) => {
  const key = JSON.stringify(a);
  if (hash.has(key)) {
    return `${hash.get(key)} memo`;        
  }
  const val = fn(...a);
  hash.set(key, val);
  return val;
};

const add = (x, y) =>  x + y;

const mAdd = memo(add, new Map());


console.log(mAdd(2,2));
console.log(mAdd(2,2));
```

Note: your code is not readable at all. So I had to edit it a bit to make it more understandable.

Comment: It was the Key creation and the .has method I was missing!  Thanks for the reference also!

Comment: _"Objects can't be used as key in Map"_ They can.

Comment: @zeroflagL do you have a better answer?  I really don't like to stringify the arguments to create a key

Comment: @zeroflagL is right. Matthew Harwood have a look to my updated post.

Comment: @zeroflagL is you do not want to stringify arguments to create a key then you could substitute a unique property from objects passed in for the objects themselves, e.g. {uid: "123",name:"joe"} you would use "123". Also concatenating a bunch of strings to create an overall key even for primitives is pretty slow. See [iMemoized](https://github.com/anywhichway/iMemoized) for an example of indexed memoization using regular JavaScript objects for the cache.